# systemd: how to recognize socket activation in application?

Tags: sockets, service, systemd

My application may be started by systemd socket activation or (end-user's choice) directly as service. In the former case, I like to code my application that it shuts down after a given idle time (and will be restarted by systemd once a new connection is received); in the latter case it should not shut down.

How can my application distinguish whether it has been started by systemd through socket activation versus by 'systemctl start myapplication'?

The systemd logs gave me no hints. Is it possible at all to distinguish those two startup cases?

Al_

PS: in case it matters: my application is written in C++/Qt and follows the systemd 'notify' scheme.

Answer (score 0):

In the latter case it will have to listen at a TCP socket. So if you *can* listen at that socket, `systemd` isn't, so you weren't started by `systemd`.

Comment: Thanks. This works only if the socket is not listening. If the socket has previously been started (with `systemctl --user start myapplication.socket` or automatically at login), and subsequently the application is started then the application cannot open the socket (already open). This behavior is the same whether the application is directly started or started by socket activation.